# Check space consumed by dynamic web app

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome

How can I check the space on disk consumed by a dynamic web app?

I want to know the sum of the size of the CSS files, script files, and images of a dynamic web app.

---

It's an online website, so I don't have access to the root folder to check the size, and in the folder would be files that are not actually sent to the client, because the content is sent as requested using AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome you can open the "Developer Tools" window (Wrench > Tools > Developer Tools, or Ctrl+Shift+I) and switch to the "Network" tab. Then on the page you want to check, hold down shift and click refresh to force a fresh load without loading from your cache. After everything is loaded, you should see the total number of requests and the number of bytes transferred.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: i cant it to load with uncached images, how do i do taht? (shift+refresh isnt working)

Comment: @AronisMariano It seems to still load some files from the cache occasionally. See http://superuser.com/questions/220179/how-can-i-do-a-cache-refresh-in-google-chrome for some ideas. If you disable the cache completely, don't forget to re-enable it when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the file size (in you filesystem, whether Windows, Mac, or whatever) of the folder that holds all that stuff :-)

Comment: If for some odd reason you have all those files distributed across your computer, and not in one folder, you could also try using a webpage-saving app or plug-in, and then looking at the file size of that.  For instance, Internet Explorer has a "Save as" option you can use.  However, the resulting file sizes from such things might be unreliable, as they might (for instance) duplicate files.